# How to trigger a setter when declaring a class property?

Tags: python

I have a class; let's call it `Foo`. It has a `key_type` class attribute, which contains a type:

```python
class Key: pass

class Foo:
  key_type = Key
```

I would like to run some method on the key type when it's initialized(*) and whenever it changes.

So I made `key_type` a property in a metaclass:

```python
class Key: pass
class OtherKey: pass

class MetaFoo(type):
  _key_type = None

  @property
  def key_type(cls):
    return cls._key_type

  @key_type.setter
  def key_type(cls, value):
    print(f'Setting key_type to {value}')
    cls._key_type = value

class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
  key_type = Key

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(f"Foo's key type: {Foo.key_type}")
  Foo.key_type = OtherKey
  print(f"Foo's key type: {Foo.key_type}")
```

Output:

```
Foo's key type: None
Setting key_type to <class '__main__.OtherKey'>
Foo's key type: <class '__main__.OtherKey'>
```

It seems like the definition of `_key_type` in the meta class overrode the definition of `key_type` in the main class. But most importantly, the setter was not called with the `Key` type.

Expected output:

```
Setting key_type to <class '__main__.Key'>
Foo's key type: <class '__main__.Key'>
Setting key_type to <class '__main__.OtherKey'>
Foo's key type: <class '__main__.OtherKey'>
```

(*) The reason I also want it to happen when it's initialized is that Foo can be inherited from. I want to know (either in MetaFoo or in Foo) if a child class uses a different `key_type`.

Comment: Note that the class body assigns to a temporary class namespace. You may want to check whether the keys fed to the namespace of type.__prepare__ are actually assigned, not just copied.

Comment: Indeed; the initial assignment to `key_type` occurs before there is an instance of the metaclass (i.e., your class `Foo`) to *have* a property. You are just assigning to a name that will *become* a property after the metaclass has been called.

Answer (score 4):

The definition of `key_type` in `class Foo` actually added a key-value pair to the third parameter (which is a dict) for the initialization of `MetaFoo`, nothing else it will do.

Therefore, you can manipulate the initialization of `MetaFoo` to explicitly call your setter method. This can be done by overriding `__init__` method of your metaclass:

```python
class Key: pass
class OtherKey: pass

class MetaFoo(type):
  _key_type = None

  @property
  def key_type(cls):
    return cls._key_type

  @key_type.setter
  def key_type(cls, value):
    print(f'Setting key_type to {value}')
    cls._key_type = value

  def __init__(self, name, bases, kw):
    super(MetaFoo, self).__init__(name, bases, kw)
    for key, val in kw.items():
       setattr(self, key, val)


class Foo(metaclass=MetaFoo):
  key_type = Key

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(f"Foo's key type: {Foo.key_type}")
  Foo.key_type = OtherKey
  print(f"Foo's key type: {Foo.key_type}")
```

The output:

```
Setting key_type to <class '__main__.Key'>
Foo's key type: <class '__main__.Key'>
Setting key_type to <class '__main__.OtherKey'>
Foo's key type: <class '__main__.OtherKey'>
```